# Spring MVC dynamic view + handling non existing views

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm going to implement a Spring MVC controller which uses dynamic view passed as a parameter to view:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/page")
public class PageController  {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{page}", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public ModelAndView page(@PathVariable("page")String page) {
        System.out.println("page = " + page);

        return new ModelAndView(page);
    }
}
```

Views are resolved by UrlBasedViewResolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="cache" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Is there any way to return a default view when non-existing view requested? Maybe to do check if there's no view exists, then return `new ModelAndView('requested_page_not_found')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with `UrlBasedViewResolver` and friends. Once the chain has reached it, you're committed -- if the view [doesn't exist](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html), you're going to be directed to whatever 404 page your container has configured.

> Note: When chaining ViewResolvers, a UrlBasedViewResolver always needs to be last, as it will attempt to resolve any view name, no matter whether the underlying resource actually exists.