# How to have a class annotated by ControllerAdvice to handle different types of exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, internal-server-error

I have a class called `GlobalExceptionHandler` that is annotated by `ControllerAdvice`. It properly handle all `NoHandlerFoundExceptions`. I added a new method to to handle `InternalError` exceptions but it does not handle such exceptions; therefore, I am still receiving `HTTP Status 500`.

Based on this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) the exception class of  `500 (Internal Server Error)` is `ConversionNotSupportedException`.

I tried following codes but none of the catch Internal Server Error.

**1**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String handleExceptionNotFound(NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("not found");
        return "redirect:/error";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ConversionNotSupportedException.class)
//  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String handleExceptionsInternalError(ConversionNotSupportedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("internal error");
        return "redirect:/error";
    }

}
```

**2**

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConversionNotSupportedException.class)
public String handleExceptionsInternalError(HttpServletRequest req, ConversionNotSupportedException ex) {
```

**3**

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String handleExceptionsInternalError(ConversionNotSupportedException ex) {
```

Exception that I need to handle is as follows:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not resolve view with name 'user' in servlet with name 'myproject'
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'user' in servlet with name 'myproject'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1211)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: There are many many possible reasons for a 500 errors, you can have a method that handles Exception, which will be called if no other exception handler exists for that specific exception

Comment: @6ton Would you give me a code sample?

Comment: @6ton I wrote a commend for him. It does not catch the exception.

Comment: Can you add stack trace that you see when the exception occurs

Comment: @6ton the stack trace is included.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your exception handler is returning an invalid view, which results in an exception in the code that calls the exception handler. See [DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%2Corg.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain%2Corg.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView%2Cjava.lang.Exception%29)

In this case the exception is thrown from the DispatcherServlet itself, and the only way to handle it is through [web.xml](https://blog.whitehatsec.com/error-handling-in-java-web-xml/)

You need to fix your exception handler to return a valid view. The other answers to handle using `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` are valid and can be used to handle exceptions thrown from your controllers.

**Update**:
Based on the @Jack's comment that the exception is caused by a controller returning a view that does not exist (and not the exception handler as I originally thought). Once you return a view, the container calls the view resolver to render it and if that throws an exception, the exception handler will not be invoked (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607229/spring-mvc-dynamic-view-handling-non-existing-views) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278183/how-do-i-check-if-a-view-exists))- the easy solution is to handle it in web.xml.

Another option is to override the view resolver.resolveViewName, say you are using [InternalResourceViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html) which could look like this:

```
public class CustomViewResolver extends InternalResourceViewResolver {
    @Override
    public View resolveViewName(String viewName,
                            Locale locale) throws Exception {
        try{
            return super.resolveViewName();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //log
            return new InternalResourceView("urlForErrorView");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception handler is returning a valid view. The controller is returning view name (in Daniel's case) 'user'  that is invalid. I used @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) but it does not handle the exception. Please give me a sample code to make sure I implemented it in a correct way.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like controller advice is not able to handle such exception. I added following code to my `web.xml` to handle this exception. If you have any better solution please let me know. Thanks.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errorhandler</location>
</error-page>
```